# I want to listen to my keyboard through my interface without using a DAW and/or Audacity

Tags: ableton, live, keyboard, interface, motu

I have a Juno-DS88 keyboard and a Motu M4 audio interface. Right now I have TRS cables connected from the outputs of my keyboard to the 1-2 inputs of my Motu interface. I also have cables connected from the 1-2 outputs of the Motu interface to my speakers. And I have my headphones plugged into the headphone jack of the Motu interface. Usually, if I want to hear myself play, I would have just listened through my headphones via my keyboard's headphone jack. But I'm going to start producing. So I started using Ableton Live to listen to myself play live on my keyboard using the interface. But there was a problem. I would have to create an audio track in Ableton Live, and set it to 'In' on the sidebar on the right in the Ableton Live arrangement view. Then I would be able to hear myself play live so long as I was recording.

But I'm not worried about recording anything now, really. I just do not want to have to continuously switch between connecting my headphones directly to my keyboard, and then back to the interface every time I want to merely play, and then do something in Ableton, and then just go back to playing, etc.

So, let's say I want to listen to Spotify while I play with my keyboard. And then after I'm done I want to record something in Ableton. I want to do that without having to disconnect any cables. So I was using Audacity for a while trying to see if I could listen to myself play there as well. But I can only get a waveform to appear when I record, and then listen back to it. I cannot hear the keyboard live as I play. The only time I am able to hear myself play live through my interface is when I record and play on an audio track in Ableton Live.

General audio from my computer comes through my headphones just fine, but I want to hear my Juno-DS88 through the computer/interface. Maybe there is some alternative or some kind of splitter I could use. Idk.I just want a good set up for convenience so I can create and just play and do whatever at my leisure.